# how to generate serial numbers for each foreign key and insert them in a different table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

How do I can generate serial no for each refno no and insert them to a different table B .Invoice number will be generate based on Table B( - MAX()+1 from Table B) ? 
MS SQL 2012

```
Table A

packname                            refno
----------------------------------- -----------
Demo 250 Channels                   1
qqq                                 1
qqq                                 3
qqq                                 3
Demo 250 Channels                   1
Demo 250 Channels                   1

Result I want
Table B

packname                            refno      InvoiceNo
----------------------------------- --------------------
Demo 250 Channels                   1                1
qqq                                 1                2
qqq                                 1                3
qqq                                 3                1
Demo 250 Channels                   3                2
Demo 250 Channels                   5                1
```

Comment: It looks like you need a `row_number() over (partition by refno order by packname)` but I couldn't make sense of the relationship between your before and after.

Comment: my table A is a transaction table and at end of the  week its generate consolidated transaction of my each customer (refno) and generate invoice- Table B and send it to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
SELECT packname, refno,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY refno ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) InvoiceNo
FROM Table1
```

You can change `(SELECT 1)` to one of columns. Otherwise results in the same group can be positioned randomly.

Comment: Thanks, Pawel Dyl. This process run every day and fetch some record and insert into Table2 so when we insert in table2 first time then its OK, but when we run this on second time then its generate duplicate number.